# Hoy to get exactly inverse prediction results? - sklearn predicts perfectly wrong

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, neural-network, confusion-matrix

My models are predicting perfect wrong outcomes. For a two classes clasification problem, there is a lot of false positives and false negatives. In fact I would have a nice result if I could get just the opposite ones. So I have a simple snippet like the following:

```
clf = neural_network.MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5
                                   , hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2)
                                   , random_state=1, max_iter=5000)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('TRAIN')
print(classification_report(y_train, clf.predict(X_train)))
print(confusion_matrix(y_train, clf.predict(X_train)))
print('\nTEST')
print(classification_report(y_test, clf.predict(X_test)))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, clf.predict(X_test)))
```

And the confusion matrix is something like

```
[[2 7]
 [8 2]]
```

So, I could use an output like

```
[[8 2]
 [2 7]]
```

How can I achieve this without operating directly on the results?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could revert the labels in training. But I would scratch my head and wonder if that result is due to some random factor, or if there is an error in the report code (did you write it?) or something else. I would definitely not trust this model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a original dataframe:

```
X,y
```

and you did:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Then the code is correct. That means don't change anything in the output. Would you could do, run another train/test-split to see how the results are changed.
You just have a bad classifier, but don't manually tune it, thats bullshit.